# android - replace only content in the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a MainActivity, which contains ImageView, TextView and 3 clickable Buttons.

After clicking the button, I want to change something in SQlite dtb and according that load different data, but show it again in the same activity.

```
     public void ClickBtn(View v)
    {
//insertData(String...

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So generally - in Main Activity.js I am getting the data from ID, which was clicked before and show that data. The MainActivity should be used infinity times to show different data.

The layout will be always the same - ImageView, TextView and 3 clickable Buttons, just the text will be different.

The question is, how can I only change content inside the same Activity? 
I don't think `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);` from the current activity can open the same activity...

Comment: get new data and update your views

Comment: should I use invalidate() on the button click? e.g. ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);vg.invalidate(); and then instead of Intent use setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen); ?

Comment: u can use setText etc to update View, though you can change the layout as well using setcontentview

Answer (score 1):

You really need to study the basics.

When you are working in android, XML layout files are merely blueprints which ultimately are parsed into a reflection-created anonymous view instance, which contains as children each of the members of the XML layout, with the valid XML tag parameters applied to them. Therefore, you aren't dealing with 'Layouts', but with java/kotlin objects, which can be:

- Referenced
- Mutated
- Replaced

So, if you want to change the contents, the first steps is to keep a reference to each object: ImageView, TextView and Buttons, and move the code in charge of filling them to a new method, so you can call it either when loading the activity (onCreate), or when clicking the button. That way the same activity can perform the same action over and over.

Finally, constant recreation of an activity is a TERRIBLE idea. For every object you generate (and an activity IS an object, like everything else), you need X+Y memory, where X is the sum of all the members of the object's class, and Y is the sum of all the operations necessary for instantiation, so by recreating the activity constantly, you waste the device resources, with the added problem of generating a huge backstack of identical activities.

Take a look at a java book, then a kotlin one. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I don't want to recreate activity, I want just to change the text inside that activity, without recreating it. Like in HTML I can replace the content infinity times of a DIV without refreshing a page, so this must be possible also on android.

Comment: ok, I think this is workin - in my onclik I just put this   String txt = "testing";
        TextView viewx = findViewById(R.id.texto);
        viewx.setText(txt);  And the text is changed without refreshing activity

Comment: Yeah,  viewx is a reference to the textView, therefore alterations done to the reference will modify the actual object in the screen. In object oriented languages, this is how you "refresh" something. Don't make the mistake of confusing android XML with HTML, web frontend and JVM platforms are pretty different.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. Just replacing text without refreshing activity. Tested it hundred times also via Memory monitoring and absolutely no impact on device memory.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



//get from dtb
        int room = 1; int a1 = 2; int a2 = 3; int a3 =4;

        TextView views = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        views.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              //get from dtb - img, text where room = a1;

                        TextView vv = findViewById(R.id.textof);
                vv.setText("text from dtb");
            }
        });


        TextView view2 = findViewById(R.id.text2);
        view2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get from dtb - img, text where room = a2;

                TextView vv = findViewById(R.id.textof);
                vv.setText("another text from dtb");
            }
        });
    }
```